# How to find a string and replace a substring of it in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string like following,

```
# Blender v2.72 (sub 0) OBJ File: 'untitled.blend'
# www.blender.org
mtllib test03.mtl
o Cube.001
v 3.851965 0.040851 6.046364
v 3.851965 0.087396 6.092909
v -3.851965 0.087396 6.092909
```

I need to read the `3rd line(mtllib test03.mtl)` and replace the `test03.mtl` with `test04.mtl`. Then the final line should be like following,

```
# Blender v2.72 (sub 0) OBJ File: 'untitled.blend'
# www.blender.org
mtllib test04.mtl
o Cube.001
v 3.851965 0.040851 6.046364
v 3.851965 0.087396 6.092909
v -3.851965 0.087396 6.092909
```

I tried to do it with the following code,

```
NSString* str= @"mtllib test03.mtl";

// Search from back to get the last space character
NSRange range= [str rangeOfString: @"mtllib " options:NSBackwardsSearch];

// Take the first substring: from 0 to the space character
NSString* finalStr = [str substringToIndex: range.location];
NSLog(@"%@", finalStr);
```

but failed to loads the line(`mtllib test03.mtl`) from above lines.
How can I fix this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What does "failed to loads the line" mean??

Comment: I need to replace the word after `mtllib`

Comment: What does "failed to loads the line" mean??

Comment: Have you tried with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method?

Comment: that means i failed to load it as `mtllib test03.mtl`

Comment: @Kampi. yes i want to replace the words after `mtllib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^mtllib (.*)$" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"mtllib test04.mtl"];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

And solution without regexp:

```
NSString *str = @"# Blender v2.72 (sub 0) OBJ File: 'untitled.blend'\n\
# www.blender.org\n\
mtllib test03.mtl\n\
o Cube.001\n\
v 3.851965 0.040851 6.046364\n\
v 3.851965 0.087396 6.092909\n\
v -3.851965 0.087396 6.092909";
NSString *finalStr = str;

// Find "mtllib" substring
NSRange range= [str rangeOfString: @"mtllib " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
// This is location of filename, now we need to find it's range
CGFloat fileNameLocation = range.location + range.length;
// Find first end of line after "mtllib" substring
NSRange newlineRange = [str rangeOfString:@"\n" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(fileNameLocation, str.length-fileNameLocation)];
if (newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSRange filenameRange = NSMakeRange(fileNameLocation, newlineRange.location - fileNameLocation);
    finalStr = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:filenameRange withString:@"test04.mtl"];
} else {
    // Assume, there is no more data in string, only filename
    NSRange filenameRange = NSMakeRange(fileNameLocation, str.length - fileNameLocation);
    finalStr = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:filenameRange withString:@"test04.mtl"];
}
NSLog(@"%@", finalStr);
```

Comment: Thanks.. with regex is better.. :)